Why does applying boost to state reduction give an incorrect result?
Suppose we have a state $|\psi \rangle (t)$ in quantum field theory. Till $t=t_0$, the state evolves unitarily using field Hamiltonian $\int d^3x H(x)$. At time $t=t_0$, we perform a measurement and the state reduces to another state $|\psi \rangle (t_0)$. This means that there is a discontinuous change in the state at $t_0$, prior to which the state evolved. continuously
Now, the generator of boosts in the $z$-direction $$K_z(t)=\int d^3x ( H(x)x-P_z(x)t),$$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian density and $P_z$ is the $z$ momentum density
If we perform $e^{i\theta K_z(t)}(|\psi \rangle (t))$, and assuming that $K$ acts continuously on the states, we get a state $|\psi '\rangle (t)$, which evolves continuously till $t=t_0$ and has a discontinuous change at $t_0$.
How do we interpret this boosted wavefunction? The problem I have is that it implies that the state reduction (the discontinuity) happens at the same time $t_0$ for both the original observer and the boosted observer. But it shouldn't be that way because time is relative, e.g. if the local observable at $(x,t_0)$ was measured in frame 1, then frame 2 should see the measurement event at $(x',t')$ which is given by a Lorentz transform.

Nothing discontinuous happens to the wavefunction when it is measured. It is just that we are no longer interested in the parts of the wavefunction that  do not correpond to the measured result, so we stop keeping track of them.

@mikestone That is Many Worlds. I would like this addressed from the standard viewpoint. in which there's state reduction upon measurement

I don't fully understand your question, but let me point to the work of Peres ("Classical interventions in quantum systems. II. Relativistic invariance") and Peres and Torno ("Quantum information and relativity theory"), where the author(s) show/argue that there are situations where both observers assign states which are not Lorentz transformations of each other.

..see also section 3.1. in "Quantum Information in Relativity: The Challenge of
QFT Measurements" by Anastopoulos and Savvidou... again. I don't know if this helps you with your problem (also since all mentioned sources talk about bipartite measurements), but I just wanted to point it out.

@TobiasFünke thanks. that section is quite illuminating. I was also thinking about using a histories approach, so that everything is covariant. These developments will be really helpful.

@TobiasFünke i have a few questions, since you have studied this : 1. Are these relativistic measurement issues considered close to solved? 2. Is this approach considered good : the state is not an objective entity, but only relative to an observer, in which case we don't need to describe collapse events from different frames of references?

@TobiasFünke i would mainly like to know about the "relative state" and "relative collapse" approach. Is this approach considered viable?

I am by no means an expert (!--I am an amateur) and I haven't studied this thoroughly -- I just stumbled upon it when asking myself a very similar question to what they answer, so I really cannot answer your questions. I suggest to open a new question; also because I don't know to what extend their bipartite cases apply to your question. Anyway, as they point out that this issue does not lead to contradicting experimental predictions/results, i.e. everyone agrees with what is observed.

Also, Peres writes in his book (p.153): "Conceptual difficulties may indeed arise if you demand that every physical system, such as our pair of particles, has, at every instant, a well defined quantum state" and proceeds (next page): "However, a situation involving several observers cannot be described by a wave function with a relativistic transformation law. No single covariant state history may be defined which properly accounts for all the experimental results. [10]", where the cited source is Y. Aharonov and D. Z. Albert, Phys. Rev. D 24 (1981) 359

@TobiasFünke thank you so much. I will read what these sources say and see if they related to my problems.

There is a beautiful paper by Hellwig and Kraus
K.E. Hellwig and K.Kraus, Formal Description of Measurements in Local Quantum Field Theory
PHYSICAL REVlEW D VOLUME 1, NUMBER 2 15 JANUARY 1970
where the analysis of the "collapse of a state" in QFT was analyzed from the perspective of measurements of local observables (essentially in the Haag-Kastler framework), proving that where in spacetime the updating of the state takes place is quite arbitrary to some extent.
Essentially, physically meaningful observables are always localized in bounded regions of spacetime and collected into local algebras of operators with the property that elements of causally separated regions commute. If an observable localized in a region $R$ produced an outcome, the state changed in the causal future $J^+(R)$ of $R$. What happens outside $J^+(R) \cup J^-(R)$ is matter of convention.
In $J^-(R)$ the state is necessarily the pre-measurement one.
It is crucial to work in Heisenberg representation to develop H-K's analysis and we have to consider spacetime as a list of all possible events that took place. The perspective here is to stay at "the end of time". Within this infinite list, occurrences of state changes due to localized measurements can be described without difficulty.
More recently, that approach has been generalized by C.J. Fewster and collaborators also in globally hyperbolic curved spacetime.
Coming back to the question, as far as I understand, we are here considering an active Lorentz transformation.
Adopting  the above illustrated Heisenberg-representation framework, the action of the boost must be also considered on the region $R$ where the measured observable is located.
We are, in fact, considering two different measurement experiments connected by an active Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$.
The "discontinuity" of the state must be viewed in  spacetime: it is located on the boundary of $J^+(R)$ in the original experiment, and on the boundary of $J^+(\Lambda R)$ in the boosted experiment.
Adopting the Schroedinger picture in QFT is very often quite awkward, and I think that it is completely misleading here.

It says I need authorisation to access this paper... if you have another link, please link it. i also had two questions : 1. Is this problem considered settled? (the problem about how the state changes upon state reduction in QFT) 2. If not, is relative collapse still seen as a viable approach? I mean
the approach where there is no single objective wavefunction for all observers which we update

Interesting paper (+1) --thank you, Valter. And I just checked some citing references... so much to learn.  One citing reference is e.g. "Is the usual notion of time evolution adequate for quantum-mechanical systems'? II. Relativistic considerations" by Aharonov and Albert, 1984. They seem to disagree with Hellwig and Kraus. Also section 2 of the article "Measurement in Quantum Field Theory" by Fewster and Verch discusses briefly some (historical and opposing) viewpoints and contains references. Both might be of interest for you, @RyderRude .

Sorry, I have the authorisation through my university automatically. Regarding 1, I think that theoretically it is considered quite settled also after the recent papers by Fewster and collaborators. Sorry I do not know anything about the relative collapse…

@Tobias, I know the paper by Fewster and Verch, and I know also them personally quite well…It is an interesting topic. I am now trying to extends these ideas to the notion of localisation for relativistic particles (I have had a number of discussion with Fewster on the subject).
